# Dafny iterator: precondition and modifes clause violated

Tags: dafny

Dafny shows multiple errors when calling MoveNext() on an iterator that does nothing:

```
iterator Iter()
{}

method main()
    decreases *
{
    var iter := new Iter();
    while (true)
        decreases *
    {
        var more := iter.MoveNext();
        if (!more) { break; }
    }
}
```

The errors are on the call to iter.MoveNext():

```
call may violate context's modifies clause

A precondition for this call might not hold.
```

There is no modifies clause for main or Iter, and there is no precondition for Iter. Why is this program incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following invariant on the loop

```
invariant iter.Valid() && fresh(iter._new)
```

Then your program verifies. As usual, there's nothing wrong (dynamically) with your program, but you can have false positives at verification time due to missing annotations.

As far as I know, this invariant is *always* required when using iterators.

(A little) More information about iterators can be found in the [Dafny Reference](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/blob/master/Docs/DafnyRef/out/DafnyRef.pdf), in Chapter 16. (At least, enough information for me to remember the answer to this question.)